# sed variables substitution with bash

Tags: bash, sed

I have changed shell from `dash` to `bash 4.2.37` on Debian 7.

Now, the following does not work any longer:

```
sed -i.bak "/${VARIABLE}/d" /path/file
sed -i.bak '/'$VARIABLE'/d' /path/file
```

which yields:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 0: no previous regular expression
```

With `bash 3.2` on OS X this works as expected

Comment: you'd get this error message if `$VARIABLE` is empty. Can it be empty on purpose? What do you expect from the command in that case?

Comment: No empty. $VARIABLE its IP passed first parameter bash script.  ./script.sh IP

Comment: After see your comment it's ok. Verify that second parameter passed to script are empty. ./script.sh hostname shortname. Verify hostname with echo $1, fine, but echo $2 return empty value.

Answer (score 2):

The `sed` syntax error is the same regardless of your shell.  If `VARIABLE` is empty, that's what you get.

Changing your shell might change which variables are defined.  For example, `BASH_VERSION` will obviously only be set in Bash. Or you could have variables which are defined locally in your `.bashrc`, which Dash does not read; there is a number of other startup files which Bash uses but Dash doesn't.

What you can do is change your script to require `VARIABLE` to be set:

```
: ${variable?Not set}
```

This is a common Bourne shell idiom to exit if a variable is unset.  The `:` pseudo-command is like a comment, but it evaluates its arguments; and `${variable?Message}` when evaluated will exit the shell with `Message` if `variable` is unset.

Comment: I tend to use `${var:-default value}` more often, but when you really want to exit, using `${var?-doh}`.  Adding the `-` after the `?` or `:` makes it apply to "unset or empty" as opposed to just "unset", which is usually what I really mean when I use either of those.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap it in an if statement:

```
if [[ ! -z $VAR ]]; then 
    sed -i.bak /"${VAR}"/d test; 
fi
```

or as a oneliner:

```
if [[ ! -z $VAR ]]; then sed -i.bak /"${VAR}"/d filename.txt; fi
```

Or even simpler:

```
[[ ! -z $VAR ]] && sed -i.bak /"${VAR}"/d filename.txt
```

Original Answer:
The following works for me:

```
sed -i.bak /"$VARIABLE"/d /path/file
```

GNU Bash 4.2-2ubuntu2.1

Comment: added some alternatives